# Switch Between Local Git Repository and SSH connection in git bash

Tags: git, bash, ssh

Sup guys,
I can't seem to remember how to switch between tabs in my git bash. I'm using windows 8. I know that there is a command to put the current connection in the background, and then a command to bring it back. I want to be able to quickly switch back and forth between remote and local repositories.

I tried to search for the answer on SO with multiple keywords, couldn't find it. I first learned how to do this from a SO post, just cant remember :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't have git bash, are you looking for `&`, `bg`, `fg`?

Comment: @ray I don't think that's it, all I can remember is I had to use the ~tilde  in one of the commands

Comment: This has nothing to do with `git` or `bash`.

Comment: @twalberg thanks, I realize that now. I'm not quite a git pro yet ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ssh` command uses `~` as an escape character; if that is the first character on the line, the input is sent to the `ssh` process itself, rather than to the remote command. For example, `~^Z` (tilde, control-Z) will suspend the `ssh` process, which you can resume with the `fg` command. See the section under "Escape Characters" in the `ssh` man page for more details.